# How do I keep the logo level on the left side of the name and title?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the logo and name/title to look like the image below. And when the display screen is reduced to a smaller size I want the logo to remain on the left side of the name/title.(right now the logo jumps up above) Please advise! Thanks!

[image: Logo, Name, Title]

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <figure>
                <img id = "title-logo" src="Images/Logo.png" width="100" height="100" class= "img-responsive" alt="Udacity_logo">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <section class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
            <h1 class="title-super text-thin">Jane Doette</h1>
            <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
        </section>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.title-super, .text-thin {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #2d3c49;
    font-weight: 200;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
.title-logo {
    margin-top: 20px;

}
```

Comment: Front-end ninja? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox: (don't have the rest of your styles so example looks bad but works)

```css
header .row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title-super,
.text-thin {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #2d3c49;
  font-weight: 200;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.title-logo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <figure>
        <img id="title-logo" src="Images/Logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="img-responsive" alt="Udacity_logo">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <section class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
      <h1 class="title-super text-thin">Jane Doette</h1>
      <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class for smaller size screen

```
<div class="col-lg-x col-md-x col-xs-x">
 <figure>
   <img id="title-logo" src="Images/Logo.png" width="100" height="100" class= "img-responsive" alt="Udacity_logo">
 </figure>
</div>
```

Where "x" is the column size. Cycle through them until you find the right one.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options